# Angular 4 Eager load lambda funciton

Tags: angular

ERROR in Error encountered resolving symbol values statically. Reference to a local (non-exported) symbol 'protectedRoutes'. Consider exporting the symbol (position 9:7 in the original .ts file), resolving symbol ProtectedRouteModule in /protected/protected.routes.ts

Please advise how to resolve this?

```
const protectedRoutes: Routes = [
      {
        path: 'protected',
        component: LayoutComponent, 
        canActivate: [AuthGuard],
        children:[
          { path:'', redirectTo: 'contact', pathMatch:'full'},
          { path:'support',  loadChildren: () => SupportModule},
          { path:'contact', loadChildren: () => ContactModule},
          // { path:'support', loadChildren:'./support/support.module#SupportModule'},
          // { path:'contact', loadChildren:'./support/contact.module#ContactModule'},
        ]
      }
    ];

    @NgModule({
      imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(protectedRoutes)],
      exports: [RouterModule]
    })
    export class ProtectedRouteModule { }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to export the function, as the error message says.

```
export function loadSupportModule() {
  return SupportModule
}
```

Then use it.

```
{ path:'support', loadChildren: loadSupportModule }
```